# Solving problem using intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continous, $g(x) = 5^\frac{x+1}{x-1} + \cot(x)$,
prove that there is $a$ $\in$ $Dg$, such that:
$$f(a) = g(a)$$

Is it enough to say that, because $\lim_{\frac{\pi}{2}-0} g(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{-\frac{\pi}{2}+0} g(x) = -\infty$, and $f$ is continous on $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, so $f$ bounded on that segment, there must be $c, d$ in that segment such that $g(c)-f(c)$ is positive and $g(d)-f(d)$ is negative, so by IVT there is $a$ between $c$ and $d$ such that $f(a)-g(a)=0$ .. ?

If that's true, how to put it formally, if it's not, why ?

Comment: What is $ctgx$?

Comment: cotangent function

Comment: Ok, I edited it to cot(x), I think that is the typical convention used for the cotangent function

Comment: I don't think I follow. Why this wouldn't work if $f(x)=g(x+4)$ ?

Comment: Oh yes, but you forgot that $f$ is continous on $R$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct. Let $$m:=\min_{x\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]}f(x),\qquad M=\max_{x\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]}f(x)$$ 
which exist finite because $f$ is continuous.
Now since $\lim_{x\to -\pi/2^+}g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \pi/2^-}g(x)=+\infty$, there is $x_1,x_2\in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ with $g(x_1)<m$ and $g(x_2)>M$. Thus by construction of $m$ and $M$ we have $g(x_2)-f(x_2)>0$ and $g(x_1)-f(x_1)<0$.

By the intermediate value theorem, you are done.

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing, it's obvious, but what theorem provides that $f$ has min and max on closed interval ?

Comment: @someone Weierstrass. And you need a compact interval , a closed interval like $[0,\infty)$ is not enough.